# Matlab, looking for the largest value in a rotated square

Tags: matlab

Let me explain:
I have a matrix sitting in Matlab that contains values of the height of terrain. I want to now the largest value inside a rectangle. However this rectangle is usually rotated with respect to the orientation of the datapoints in the matrix. To illustrate:

10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10

10 10 10 **10 10** 10 10 10 10 10

10 10 **10 10** 10 10 10 10 10 10

10 **10 10** 10 10 10 10 10 10 10

10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10

10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10

10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10

This shows a matrix where I would like to extract the data within a rectangle. Imagine a rectangle over the bold faced 10. The bold face 10 is the data I want to examine.

I understand you get a jagged edge when you do stuff like this. I actually want my jagged ' pixelated' outline to lie outside the rectangle i define. The data within the set can not change (ie., be interpolated) and I'm looking for the maximum value.

I've already been close to a solution but it didn't work out. At first it seems to be quite simple so hopefully someone with a fresh pair of eyes can help me out.

regards,
Berend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the values you're interested in by indexing, then calculate the maximum of those.

*Steve on Image Processing* has a number of posts on clever ways to do indexing: http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/category/indexing/